# What species is this "talking" bird?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5gfccWjw-I) shows a bird which appears to repeat some sounds (not speech though) after a human. Here're some cropped screenshots from the video:

[image: screenshot from the video]
[image: screenshot from the video]

What species is this bird? Can it actually mimic human speech, or are these sounds in the video its natural sounds?

Comment: A location would help narrow it down.

Comment: Unfortunately the only information I have is this video. I wasn't the one who filmed it, so I can't add much information aside from what is contained there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [black-collared starling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-collared_starling) (*Gracupica nigricollis*).

According to [the title of this other video](https://youtu.be/1XYb0ADJbWU), which is the same footage uploaded by another user and could be the original one, it has been recorded in Thailand, where the black-collared starling is common.

Also, from the same Wikipedia page:

> In Thailand the collared starling is sometimes kept in captivity and taught to speak.